# How do I (can i) set a custom error page for errors from dav_svn on ubuntu

Tags: apache, svn, mod-dav-svn

I've gotten subversion configured and functional using dav_svn.  Now i want to display a custom webpage when users try to navigate to an area they do not have permissions for.  Currently what is displayed is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<D:error xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns:m="http://apache.org/dav/xmlns" xmlns:C="svn:">
<C:error/>
<m:human-readable errcode="13">
Can't open directory '/dhproj': Permission denied
</m:human-readable>
</D:error>
```

and i cannot seem to find where this i generated, or stored.  I'm running command line Ubuntu server 12.10 with apt-get packages for apache2, dav, and subversion.  Thanks.

Comment: ErrorDocument inside Location, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is the errordocument command.  what i was missing was the proper error code.  13 isn't a valid http error code, however 403 covers this situation.  Thank you.